# Sorting an ag-grid table with a list of IP addresses by quantity of IPs and largest/smallest IP in the list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a React Ag-grid table with an IP column. Each cell in the IP column contains a list of IP addresses. I am trying to sort the data in this column as follows:

- first, sort by quantity of IPs
- next, for descending sort, sort based on largest IP in the list
- and, for ascending sort, sort based on the smallest IP in the list

```
Example:
[1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3]
[1.1.1.2]
[1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 2.2.2.5]
[2.2.2.2, 2.2.2.3, 2.2.2.4]

ascending:
[1.1.1.2]
[1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3]
[1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 2.2.2.5] (sorted based on 1.1.1.1)
[2.2.2.2, 2.2.2.3, 2.2.2.4] (sorted based on 2.2.2.2)

descending:
[1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 2.2.2.5] (sorted based on 2.2.2.5)
[2.2.2.2, 2.2.2.3, 2.2.2.4] (sorted based on 2.2.2.4)
[1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3]
[1.1.1.2]
```

Here is my column definition:

```
{
  headerName: t('tables.allIps.columns.ip.header'),
  headerTooltip: t('tables.allIps.columns.ip.desc'),
  colId: DeviceColumnIds.ip,
  valueGetter: agFields.interfaceIPSumGetter,
  comparator: agFields.listSizeComparator
}
```

And here is the **listSizeComparator**:

```
export const listSizeComparator = (list1: Array<string>, list2: Array<string>) => {
  return list1.length - list2.length;
};
```

To this point, everything is working and I can sort the column by size of IP lists. However, I can't solve the second requirement; sort each list in ascending/descending order. I have created a sort function:

```
export const ipListSort = (ipList: Array<string>) => {
  const ip2int = str => str
    .split('.')
    .reduce((acc, byte) => acc + byte.padStart(3, 0), '');

  if (ipList) {
    return ipList.sort((a, b) => ip2int(a) - ip2int(b));
  };

  return ipList;
};
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to successfully call the function and return a sorted list of IPs. I am new to React and I have been searching for solutions to a similar problem, but I can't find anything. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

One other small thing, which isn't absolutely necessary, would be to remove the default third click option when sorting the size of the IP lists. Currently, when I click on the column header it will filter ascending, then descending, and finally, default, which is unfiltered. I would prefer it to simply be ascending or descending by size.

Comment: The `listSizeComparator` could just be `list1.length - list2.length`. Also `ip2int(a) = ip2int(b)` tries to set `ip2int(a)` to `ip2int(b)`. You probably meant `==` or `===`, or `-`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and pointing out the typo. I meant ```-``` as opposed to ```=```. I also updated the **listSizeComparator**.